# codigniter 2.1.4 and ion_auth won't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I try to use ion_auth library for codeigniter but I do not get it to work. Appropriate files already in given folders, mysql structure created

I have my admin structure as follows

```
controller
--admin
---dashboard.php
---auth.php
```

I request domain/admin/dashboard
and I check if user is logged in

```
  if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            redirect('admin/auth/login', 'refresh');
        }
```

else should be able to access dashboard

than in my view I have

```
--view
---admin
---- tmpl
-----index.php
---auth
----login.php
```

than I try to log in with the default credentials

fails but I do not even get an error message. than I checked  controller/admin/auth.php login method

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    { 
        codes that would check credentials

    } else
    {
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() :    $this->session->flashdata('message');
        //and return to login view
    }
```

I try to var_dump($this->data['message']) but I get boolean false,

diving a bit deeper I was checking the form validator under /sytem/libraries/Form_validation.php

```
if (count($_POST) == 0)
        {
            return $this;
        }

var_dump(count($_POST));
```

shows on posted data `0`

**Okay get it to work!!**
Ignoring the form template coming from the framework fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I recently used **Ion-auth** in **CI 2.1.4** on Aug 7th and had no issues. Since u didn't get any *validation* message , I suspect that u didn't add the language folder of `ion-auth` and didn't load the **[language helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/language_helper.html).**

The **auth controller** was recently updated to use [error messages from language files](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/tree/2/language/english).

Hence u won't get any message unless language files are loaded.

If that is the case, i suggest autoloading the *language helper* in *config/autoload.php*.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('language');
```

and copy the language files u need from Ion auth languages folder into CI language folder.

This should solve the issue.